# Reusable Content does not accept some HTML tags

Tags: 2007

I'm trying to add the following HTML code to a reusable content list item.

```
<object width="400" height="250"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/mUH8KeiRS10?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/mUH8KeiRS10?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="400" height="250"></embed></object>
```

For some reason, when I save the changes that piece of code disappears. Are those tags not supported in reusable content items? If not, how can I reuse this kind of content among several site collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing the same thing in a normal rich text editor would do the same thing. Theres a bunch of JavaScript parsing out "unsafe" code like embed, object and script tags.

Try adding your code inside a forms web part or similar, or if you need it across pages, add it to a delegate control or web control and add it to the master or page layout.